# Не могу получить ответ от asyncio.wait_for

Tags: python, асинхронность, asyncio

Код:

```
async def waiter():
    future = asyncio.Future(loop=loop)
    futures.append(future)
    response = await asyncio.wait_for(future, None, loop=loop)

    print('Response: ', response)

def worker():
    breakl = False
    while not breakl:
        for future in futures:
            print(future)
            try:
                future.set_result('Yey!')
            except:
                breakl = True

threading.Thread(target=worker).start()
loop.run_until_complete(waiter())
```

**Output:**

```
<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001D6E3C94D08>()]>
<Future finished result='Yey!'>
```

Видно что **Future** получил результат, но **asyncio.wait_for** не возвращает его. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future):

> A Future represents an eventual result of an asynchronous operation.
>   **Not thread-safe**.

Вам придётся явно передавать цикл событий в обе функции и вызывать что-нибудь вроде

```
loop.call_soon_threadsafe(future.set_result, 'Yey!')
```

Comment: Из-за этого комментария я перечитал всю документацию и наконец-то понял как работает asyncio. Теперь у меня все как часы, спасибо вам. Не знаю где написать в лс, так что тут.